# Regex .NET OR operator not working on alternative group

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regex which validate string of numbers either math "aabb" or "abba" pattern.

*For example: both 1122 or 1221 is valid*

Regex for both "aabb", "abba" worked fine alone.
But when i'm trying to combine "aabb" OR "abba", the result of "aabb" is always false.
(1122 returned not valid)

Here is my implementation in C#:

```
string phoneNumber = "1221"; // "1122" failed
Dictionary<string, string> subPatterns = new Dictionary<string, string>();
subPatterns[@"(\d)(\d)\2\1$"] = "abba";
subPatterns[@"(\d)\1(\d)\2$"] = "aabb";
string pattern = string.Join("|", subPatterns.Select(e => e.Key));
                
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(phoneNumber, pattern))
{               
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
    }               
}
```

Did i missed something?

Comment: The alternation `|` with the capture groups changes the group numbers, it would be `(\d)(\d)\2\1$|(\d)\3(\d)\4$`

Comment: Use named capture groups, then it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks you so much, i get it now. But is there anyway i can reset the group numbers for each rules in C# regex? Because I plan to join alot of regex rules in this functions. It's going to be a mess if i just increase the group numbers.

Comment: Like this? `^(?:(?<1>\d)(?<2>\d)\k<2>\k<1>|(?<1>\d)\k<1>(?<2>\d)\k<2>)$` https://regex101.com/r/eDTY1d/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternation changes the capture group numbers. You can either account for the incremented numbers in the alternation:

```
subPatterns[@"(\d)(\d)\2\1$"] = "abba";
subPatterns[@"(\d)\3(\d)\4$"] = "aabb";
```

The pattern will look like this, matching the 4 digits at the end of the string due to the `$`

```
(\d)(\d)\2\1$|(\d)\3(\d)\4$
```

---

Or you can use the same [named backreferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-backreferences):

```
subPatterns[@"(?<1>\d)\k<1>(?<2>\d)\k<2>"] = "abba";
subPatterns[@"(?<1>\d)(?<2>\d)\k<2>\k<1>"] = "aabb";
```

The pattern will then look like

```
(?<1>\d)(?<2>\d)\k<2>\k<1>|(?<1>\d)\k<1>(?<2>\d)\k<2>
```

**Note** that if the matches are for the whole line, you can append an anchor `^` to it and the whole pattern will look like

```
^(?:(?<1>\d)(?<2>\d)\k<2>\k<1>|(?<1>\d)\k<1>(?<2>\d)\k<2>)$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eDTY1d/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/i71yWD).